# Unable to edit a css class

Tags: css, symfony

I want to add a css class to a field but I couldn't. Nothing happened:

```
->add('book', 'entity', array(
    'class' => 'MyBundle\Entity\Book',
    'attr' => array(
        'class' => 'something',
        'data-class' => 'something',
    ))
```

This will add the `HTML` attribute `data-class` but will do nothing on the class attribute.
Is it because of the `entity` type? Because I can edit the `CSS` class attribute of a normal type such as `text` and `number`

Editing the class from the twig doesn't work either:

```
{{ form_widget(form.book, {'attr': {'class': 'something'}}) }}
```

Comment: I dont know about the first code part, but in the second you are doing form.book, while in the first part the entity is mapped 'books'. So you can try fixing that, since now it is not possible to tell which one is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Since your form define books, use form.books

Else, it would be great to show us your whole form. (making sure you didn't forgot form start and form end

```
{{ form_start(form, { 'attr': { 'class': 'form-horizontal form-bordered'} }) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
        {{ form_label(form.books, 'Author', { 'attr': {'class': 'control-label'} }) }}
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        {{ form_widget(form.books, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control'} }) }}
    </div>
</div>
{{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is just wrap the form field in the div and to the styling like that:

```
<div id="test" class="something" style="display:none">
     {{ form_label(form.book) }}{{ form_widget(form.book) }}
</div>
```

Or just add a span tag for a field and do the styling this way:

```
     <span style="width: 65%">{{ form_widget(form.book) }}</span>
```